# Set up default page and Dynamic Web Project, JAX-RS

Tags: eclipse, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am trying to do a simple rest service sample with eclipse, galssfiash server, using jersey. I started project like webDynamic.I did servlet mapping with Application class.Without web.xml file:

```
 @ApplicationPath("/rest/*")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application{
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses(){
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(MyClass.class));
    }
```

And for now everything work fine. Bath how do I set default page?
On sample, when someone or I putt in address bar of web explorer only project name like:
localhost:8080/name.of.the.project/. I wish to be presented  first page like readme.xhtml where is explained rest service on sample. And if in url I add .../rest/ it will be returned by web service. How do I accomplish this. Or I can use web.xml for first page and can register sevlet with Application class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using the Applicationpath annotation, you don't need to specify servlet class in the web.xml again. You can use the web.xml to specify welcome page and still use your application class as is

Comment: How to achieve it?
During the creation of project, I can choos or selct option create web.xml file.
But how to achieve it if I did not choose that option? Can I just in already created project just make new web.xml file and fill it by hand?

Comment: Yes, you can create a web.xml and full it by hand or generate one by right clicking on the project and choose the option in the context menu